# Is there a way to generate an Excel files from R and do "styling" of the exported text?

Tags: r, excel, apache-poi

I often produce Excel files from R and I am aware of most packages for it.

I was wondering if there is any package which allows formatting or styling the exported "text ? like highlighting words in "red" or similar.

I think that the Apache POI package supports this, but I have not seen an easy R integration of this specific features.

In case there is a "higher" level library (higher then Apache POI API) in an other language, I would be happy to try that as well.
With "higher level I mean a functionality of "export a data frame to excel table. In Apache POI I needed to create my Excel file piece-by-piece.

Comment: To be precise with my question, I want to add that the R packake "openxlsx" allows to arbitrary style a whole cell.
But I want a different style for different words in a cell.

Comment: Initially I thought you need to go for [XLConnect](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf) but then I noticed that the vignette I linked to explictly states that it (also) does not offer low-level formatting beyond cell styles. You might be trying too much for a higher level library. Perhaps you could try and google around whether a LibreOffice R package exists that does enable those low-level features and then read that spreadsheet file into Excel??